# Android: sqlite only saves one item

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to save a list of books but when I read the table I only get one book.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
    ...

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME +" (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT, description TEXT)"
        );
    }

public boolean insertBook  (String id, String title, String publisher, String format,
                                String description, String creator, String category, String language, String date)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("id", id);
        contentValues.put("title", title);
        contentValues.put("description", description);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }

public List<Book> getBooks()
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=  db.rawQuery( "select * from tblbooks", null );

        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            do {
                book.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                book.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                book.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

                bookList.add(book);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return bookList;
    }
...
```

**MainActivity.java**

Here I have a for loop that changes the values in book and in this loop I've put this code so that with each new book the book will be saved:

```
...
//Save books localy
dbHelper.insertBook(    //the value of book changes, I've tested it so this is not the problem
  book.getId(),
  book.getTitle(),
  book.getDescription()
);
```

After that I use this code to get all the books from the database, this is where I only get 1 book...

```
...

//Get bookshelf of local database
    for (int i = 0; i < dbHelper.getBooks().size(); i++) {
          bookList.add(dbHelper.getBooks().get(i)); <-- should put all books in this list.
     }

    ...
```

output is always only 1 book...

Comment: Your cursor is moving to last item and your loop stop after one iteration. just change for cursor.movetofirsrt

Answer (score 2):

Just you should move

```
 Book book = new Book();
```

inside loop

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Book book = new Book();//here

            book.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
            book.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

            bookList.add(book);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

and also check `cursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: I've done this but now I get a list of the same books.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

Change from `cursor.moveToLast()` to `cursor.moveToFirst()` and always create new **Book** object inside loop.

Reason: You are requesting cursor to get Last item

Comment: I've done this but now I get a list of the same books.

Comment: @AlbinGjoka, make sure you are inserting same book in db

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Replace

cursor.moveToLast()  to  cursor.moveToFirst()

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.

1. you need to create the Book object inside the loop.
2. First move the cursor to first position & then fetch the record.

> Modified Code:-

```
public List<Book> getBooks()
    {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=  db.rawQuery( "select * from tblbooks", null );

       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  // change here
                    do {
       Book book = new Book();  // need to add here

    book.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                        book.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                        book.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

                        bookList.add(book);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
                }
        }
        return bookList;
    }
```

Comment: I've done this but now I get a list of the same books.

Comment: @Albin I have used the same code on my machine & tested it works fine. I have updated the complete method please use as it is.

Comment: very strange, but I found the problem.

Comment: @AlbinGjoka in DB there are only 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

You need modify two place

1. move the `Book book = new Book();` inside loop;
2. change `cursor.moveToLast()` to `cursor.moveToFirst()`.

Like this:

```
public List<Book> getBooks() {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+TABLE_NAME, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                book.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                book.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));
                bookList.add(book);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return bookList;
    }
```

By the way, you should not get all books like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dbHelper.getBooks().size(); i++)
```

but should like this

```
List<Book> bookList = dbHelper.getBooks();
for(int i = 0, count = bookList.size(); i < count; i++){
   ...
}
```